# How to catch the address of the functor generated for a lamda expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

you know that the compiler transforms a lambda expression into some kind of functor:

the captured variables become data members of this functor. Variables captured by value are copied into data members of the functor. These data members have the same constness as the captured variables et cetera...

Now I wonder if it's possible to catch the address of this hidden object generated from the compiler behind the scenes

I give you a simple snippet of (WRONG) code just to show my intentions:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MetaData
{
  public:
  void printAddress()
  {
    cout << "\n printAddress:Instance of MetaData at &" << this;
  }
};

int main()
{
    MetaData md1;
    cout << "\n &md1 = " << &md1 << "\n";

    md1.printAddress();

    cout << "\n\n--------------------\n\n";

    int i = 5;

    auto x = [i]() mutable {
        //cout << "\n The address of the functor is &" << this;      // ERROR  ! ! ! 
        cout << "\n Hello from Lambda ";
        cout << "\n &i = " << &i << " ++i ==> " << ++i << endl; };    

    x();    //    executing lambda

    auto y = x;        //    y is constructed with copy ctor

    y();

}
```

[Link to Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfd80cf3057a71db)

I'd like hidden functor to behave like MetaDatas.

Can someone clear my mind?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why do you need the address is still unclear to me. I guess you want to know the identity of the functor, because seem to want to know which captured variable it will effect. That smells like a big XY problem to me. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Why do you think they should generate an actual functor?  (Usually, this is true, but what's the rationale?)

Comment: @L.F.: It's true by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax would be:

```
auto x = [&](){ std::cout << &x; }; // but it is illegal too:
// variable 'x' declared with deduced type 'auto' cannot appear in its own initializer
```

Possible work-around is usage of Y-combinator, something like:

```
auto x = [i](auto& self) mutable {
    cout << "\n The address of the functor is &" << &self;
    cout << "\n Hello from Lambda ";
    cout << "\n &i = " << &i << " ++i ==> " << ++i << endl; };    

x(x);    //    executing lambda
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95970b096fd710b8)

Comment: If you throw in a `return self`, it becomes chainable and you can write `x(x)(x)`.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But now a 2nd question arises: if you comment "cout << "\n &i = " << &i << " ++i ==> " << ++i << endl; }; " the compiler gives the error: variable 'x' declared with deduced type 'auto' cannot appear in its own initializer. Why? C++ is neverending...

Comment: You comment closing } of the lambda.

Comment: @Jarod42: shame on me.